# Making Element Visible Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, element

How could I make an element visible in html? for example lets say I have a button in html

```
<button id="test" hidden="true">
```

And I would like it to become visible via js once a function is triggerd . How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to remove the hidden attribute from the button DOM Object like this:

```
function showButton(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("test");
    btn.removeAttribute("hidden");  
}
```

see a running example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hmg5zdej/

alternatively you can use the more common style rule in stead of the hidden attribute

```
 display: none;
```

If you are using jQuery, it is even more straight forward:

```
function showButton(){
    $("#test").show();  
}
```

see jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Extending Frithjof's answer. If you use `style="display:none;"` you can then use jQuery `$(elem).show();` or `$(elem).hide();` or even `$(elem).toggle();`